# Can you save whilst using the Masuda Method?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I've wondered this for a while, but when I searched on Google I couldn't find what exactly I was looking for.

So can any one tell me can you save during the Masuda method?

Answer (score 6):

Breeding Pokémon according to the Masuda Method (that is, breeding two Pokémon from different nationalities to boost the chances of receiving a shiny Pokémon) does not disable your game's save function.

Furthermore, saving and quitting then loading at any point in the process will have no effect on the chances of you receiving a shiny Pokémon.

The Masuda Method's effects occur at the moment the egg is handed to you at the daycare. Although you won't know whether the hatchling will be shiny until the egg hatches, it has already been determined and that information will be saved if you save your game.